# StrechBlt doesnt work

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, api

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
      Win32Helper.StretchBlt(this.Handle, 0, 0, 200, 300,bitmap.GetHbitmap(), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, Win32Helper.TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
      this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, 100, 100);           

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Rectangle is drawn.. But bitmap isnt... I have set `picturebox1.Image=bitmap` and works so bitmap isnt empty ...  Any idea what am i doing wrong ? 
I am in compact framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "this.Handle" is, but it might be not be a handle to a DC. And I suspect you are leaking resources as well with each creation of a Pen and Graphics object.  (The garbage collector will release it eventually, but it's not a good idea to leave these handles lingering around).  In any case, rather than thunking into StretchBlt, you could just use the Graphics object itself to do the image blit.

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
      System.Drawing.Graphics g = e.Graphics; // or call your CreateGraphics function
      Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

      g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 200, 300);
      g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, 100, 100);           

      // cleanup
      p.Dispose();
      // g.Dispose(); Call g.dispose if you allocated it and it didn't come from the PaintEventArgs parameter

      base.OnPaint(e);
  }
```

Comment: i wasnt using HDC.. DrawImage vs API performance doesnt have significant performance difference

Comment: You *might* get a slight bump in perf if you use the DC of the window handle instead of the one from PaintEventArgs. The reason being that the HDC binded to the Graphics object is "clipping" regions that aren't in need of an update.  But it may or may not matter depending on the frequency and demands your app has on the paint routine.